# SQL Select only one row based on an condition for a complete status on a two rows

Tags: sql, select

I work in logistics, and I am trying to select a row of data based on a condition, which requires a second row, but then excludes it as an outcome.

As an example, we have staged deliveries in logistics - there is a trip leg and a shuttle leg, which both represent a unique row in my data but are joined by a batch key. I only want to select the trip leg in the data, but only if both legs are complete.

```
Shipment id / Batch key / Leg type / Status
1 / 22 / Trip / Complete
2 / 22 / Shuttle / Complete
```

Output (Only if both leg statuses are complete, otherwise the data is excluded)

```
1 / 22 / Trip / Complete
```

Any ideas/ support would be helpful.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on complete trips, and use `exists` to ensure that another record exists for the same `batch_key` with a complete shuttle:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.leg_type = 'Trip'
    and t.status = 'Complete'
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1 
        where 
            t1.batch_key = t.batch_key 
            and t1.leg_type = 'Shuttle'
            and t1.status = 'Complete'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `exists`?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.legtype = 'Trip' and
      t.status = 'Complete' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.batchkey = t.batchkey and
                    t2.legtype = 'Shuttle' and
                    t2.status = 'Complete'
             );
```

Or aggregation:

```
select min(shipment_id), batchkey, max(legtype), max(status)
from t
where legtype = ('Trip', 'Shuttle')
group by batchkey
having count(*) = 2;
```

Or even a self-join:

```
select tt.*
from t tt join
     t ts
     on tt.batchkey = ts.batchkey and
        tt.legtype = 'Trip' and
        tt.status = 'Complete' and
        ts.legtype = 'Shuttle' and
        ts.status = 'Complete' ;
```

Comment: Thank you - exists works really nicely... Now one further request, what if I also have direct as a trip leg type that I want to include, it is much simpler as it only has one batch_key, but I want to add these entries

Comment: You can use the `exists` query and add `and legtype = 'direct'`.